# PowerBI clustered column sort not working after publishing

Tags: powerbi, column-chart

I am trying to sort a column chart in descending order (columns are percentages of different medical specialities). This works fine when I use 'sort by descending' > '%'.

However, when I publish the sort reverts to alphabetical order of the specialities themselves, so the columns do not make a neat descending line, but are all over the place.

I can resort on the published version, but it again reverts when I move from tab to tab in the dashboard. Any advice on how to make it stick?

Comment: What you exacly sorting? Table? Visualization? Add more info.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.